# Google Analytics iOS Button Tracking

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics

I am trying to track how many times users tap a certain button by using Google Analytics. I was following the Google Analytics SDK, but  I am getting an "Use of Undeclared Idtenifier 'CallHotline'" error, With the following code:

```
[[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                    withAction:@"buttonPress"
                     withLabel:callHotline
                     withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

Answer (score 0):

is 'callHotline' a string literal? then use:

```
[tracker sendEventWithCategory:@"uiAction"
                    withAction:@"buttonPress"
                     withLabel:@"callHotline"
                     withValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:100]];
```

the `Category`, `Action`, and `Label` fields are all strings.

Note that in the code you provided, you also had an unnecessary `[` at the start of the line.

Comment: When I changed my code it gave me an error on the top line saying
"No known instance method for selector 'sendEventWithCategory:withAction:withLabel:withValue'"